# Oribasii Collectiones Medicae in Greek/English

Tags: translation, greek-language, oribasius

I'm seeking a Greek-English translation of Oribasii Collectiones Medicae. I'm specifically looking for the section describing the setting of a dislocated limb where an interesting Greek verb (καταρτίζω) is used by Oribasius [AD 325–397]. I've found a Greek/Latin work but as yet I haven't found a Greek/English work. Is anyone aware of such a work?

Comment: There's a [Greek/French edition here](https://archive.org/details/b29003532_0001/page/n69/mode/2up)

Comment: Thank you Gareth. It's not looking to good for a Greek/English edition!

Answer (score 1):

The verb καταρτίζω is used many times in book 49, chapter 12, titled Πῶς κεκλιμένον τὸν ϖάσχοντα δεῖ καταρτίζειν (how to reduce dislocations when the patient is lying down), where it means “[reduce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_(orthopedic_surgery))”, that is, correct the alignment of the dislocated bones. Here’s a typical passage from the chapter:

> Διὰ ταῦτα ἔδοξεν αὑτώ ὑπὲρ τὸ κάταγμα βρόχον ϖεριτιθέναι, καὶ ϖρῶτον τὸ εξάρθρημα καταρτίζειν, εἷτα μετὰ τοῦτο τὸ κάταγμα. Ἀριστίων δὲ ὐπὸ τὸν αὐτὸν καιρὸν ἠθέλησεν ἀμφότερα τὰ συμπtώματα καταρτίζειν ἐὰν γὰρ ϖρῶτον τὸ ἐξάρθρημα καταρτισθῇ, ἐν τῇ τοῦ κατάγματος καταρτίσει υπόγυος κατηρτισμένη η κεφαλή του βραχίονος ἐκπεσεῖται.
>
> Pour cette raison, Pasicrate jugea qu'il fallait placer le lacs au-dessus de la fracture, et réduire d’abord la luxation, pour passer ensuite à la fracture. Aristion voulait, au contraire, remédier dans la mème séance aux deux accidents : en effet, si l’on réduit d’abord la luxation, la tête de l’humérus récemment rentrée quittera l’articulation au moment où on réduit la fracture.
>
> For this reason, he [Pasicrates] judged that it was necessary to place the ligature above the fracture, and first reduce the dislocation, and then move on to the fracture. Aristion wanted, on the contrary, to remedy in the same operation the two injuries: indeed, if the dislocation is reduced first, the head of the humerus just reduced will leave the joint at the moment when the fracture is reduced.
>
> <sub>Oribasius (c. 400). [*Medical Collections* 49.12](https://archive.org/details/b24757755_0004/page/390/mode/2up). French translation by Ulco Cats Bussemaker & Charles Daremberg (1862). *Oeuvres d’Oribase*, volume 4, p. 388. Paris: L’imprimerie impériale.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your response pointing me to this particular reference. I've been on the road so sorry for the delay — currently in Burnside, KY. The translation you provided shed some much needed light on the topic I'm researching. Again, thanks so much!

Comment: @edhuff What topic are you researching and what led you to Oribasius?

Comment: Hi Gareth, see my comment regarding 'English translation of Corpus Hippiatricorum Graecorum.' Thanks!

Comment: @edhuff So you're looking at [Strong's Greek 2675](https://biblehub.com/greek/2675.htm)?

Comment: Hi Gareth! Currently outside of Dallas, TX., but let me offer a Cliff Notes version of my studies. In translating the New Testament and the LXX (Septuagint), I'll find a word such as 'καταρτίζετε' used by the Apostle Paul in his epistle to the Galatians (6,1) and using the resource under 'perseus.tuftd.edu' I'll enter the 'rabbit hole' of various usages. I love to go down these paths to understand more fully the meaning of a word and how its been used down through the annals of time. I'm not content to just take a translator's 'word for it.' BTW, I had a longer response, but I was cut off!

Comment: @edhuff Thanks for replying! I have some advice going forwards, which is to ask your question directly, rather than putting it into the form of a reference request, for example, "where did Oribasius use καταρτίζω and what did he mean by it?". This would allow people writing answers to use English translations if they exist, or translate the relevant passage directly, or some combination of the two. Also, background is worth including, e.g. if you are interested in whether Oribasius might shed some light on [Galatians 6:1](https://biblehub.com/text/galatians/6-1.htm) then mention that too.

Comment: Thanks for that advice which I'll definitely implement going forward. Again, thanks for taking the time to get back to me.

Comment: @edhuff These types of questions are welcome over at the [Latin site](https://latin.stackexchange.com/) as well. Ancient Greek is not only on topic there, but you'll find many of us expert in it as well.

Comment: Thank you, cmw. I wish I had a working knowledge of Latin but I usually have to resort to a translation engine to do the 'heavy lifting.' Again, thanks for the advice.