# Tebtunis Papyri - The Land Survey

Tags: greek-language

I'm trying to find an English translation of The Land Survey within the Tebtunis Papyri. Thanks!
I've included the section I'm particularly interested in which is designated as "61(b) 237f" which appears to be the text entitled "The Land Survey" (60-88). The actual Greek text begins at line 235: the Greek word in question is in line 238.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not convinced this is on topic for LitSE but is this any help? https://papyri.info/search?SERIES=P.Tebt.&DATE_END_TEXT=0&DATE_END_ERA=CE&DATE_MODE=LOOSE&TRANSL=en&page=1

Comment: Could you give some background as to why you are interested in this papyrus? This would make the question more compelling for people trying to answer it. [You previously said](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/17336/oribasii-collectiones-medicae-in-greek-english/23252#comment35082_23252) that you would "definitely implement [this advice] going forward". Also, you might at the very least help us out by giving the papyrus number, as there are multiple land surveys in the Tebtunis papyri.

Comment: Yes, so sorry about that Gareth. There's a Greek word, ἀνεπίλημστος, that is of particular interest to me and that is rare in the extant Greek writings we have as well as the Canon of scripture. A single occurrence of the word is found in this papyri at location 61(b), 238 which I researched as in The Land Survey within the Tebtuni Papyri. The reference that Matt included is helpful but finding the correlation between the listings in papyri.info and the actual Greek text location as I wrote above is a bit challenging: just looking for a path of lesser resistance w/o the trial and error!

Answer (score 2):

The editors of the *The Tebtunis Papyri* included translations in the notes. The passage you asked about is this one:

> ο[ἷ]ς ἐπικεχώρηται κατὰ τὰ περὶ αὐτῶν ἰδίαι πρ[οστ]εταγμέ[να] ἔχειν
> οἵους ποτὲ καταμεμέτρηνται κλήρους ἀ[σ]υκοφαντή[τους] καὶ
> ἀκατηγορήτους καὶ ἀνεπιλήμ<π>του[ς πάσαις αἰτίαις ὄντ]ας:
>
> List of those who have been permitted in accordance with the special orders issued with regard to them to retain their allotments as they were originally assigned to them, free from calumniation or accusation or confiscation on any pretext:
>
> <sub>[Tebtunis papyrus 61(b), column viii, lines 236–238](https://archive.org/details/tebtunispapyri04gren/page/202/mode/2up). In Bernard P. Greenfell, Arthur S. Hunt & J. Gilbart Smyly, eds. (1902), [*The Tebtunis Papyri*, part 1, p. 221](https://archive.org/details/tebtunispapyri04gren/page/220/mode/2up). London: Henry Frowde.</sub>

So the editors translated ἀνεπιλήμπτους as “free from confiscation”.

Comment: Gareth, thanks for the reference. Is the actual papyrus plate/leaf containing the Greek text available online to peruse somewhere in the site?

Comment: Yes, it can be accessed via [http://papyri.info/ddbdp/p.tebt;1;61b](http://papyri.info/ddbdp/p.tebt;1;61b).

Comment: Thanks again. Yikes! I could handle deciphering many of the manuscripts of the New Testament thanks to Bruce Metzger with whom I wanted to do my graduate studies at Princeton, but this verso takes it to another level for sure.

Comment: The papyrus is not in the best condition, but we have to take into consideration that for two thousand years it was wrapped around a mummified crocodile.

Comment: Yes, I suppose that would age anything :-) Again, thanks.